# Not able to run a category in Junit4 tests

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

Have a test method annotated with category:

```
public interface BVT {} //is placed in package net.test.categories, file name BVT.java

public class TestClass{
    @Test
    @Category(BVT.class)
    public void someTest(){
        System.out.println("smoke");
    } }
```

I use Junit 4.12 and surefire 3.0.0-M3

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>${threadCount}</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <skip>false</skip>
        <groups>${testGroup}</groups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If I try to run test from BVT category

```
 mvn clean test -DtestGroup="net.test.categories.BVT"
```

I get

```
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Have no ideas why the test was not run/skipped...
Using of created in pom profile didn't help - it just runs all the tests.
Adding this runner dependency also doesn't help:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Creating a Suite runs the needed test but I don't want to list all required classes in this suite class, just want to run a certain group from command line

Comment: Remove surefire-junit47 dependency. Let surefire-maven-plugin. decide on it's own.

Comment: @khmarbaise, well I tried to add and then removed this dependency. It doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find reason, but adding include section in surefire configuration solved the issue.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>${threadCount}</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <skip>false</skip>
        <groups>${testGroup}</groups>
        <includes>
            <include>*</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: If this is the solution, then your test cases are not following the default naming conventions, described here https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html#Using_JUnit_Categories):

> You can use JUnit categories by using the `groups` parameter.

Using `mvn -D...` sets a *system property*, not a plugin parameter.

So you need something like:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <groups>${myGroup}</groups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And run it with `mvn ... -DmyGroup="net.test.categories.BVT"`

Comment: It doesn't help. I have already tried to add <groups>net.test.categories.BVT</groups> directly in pom.xml and it didn't work

Comment: @Roman In that case I would say something else is going on. Are you able to remove all the categories stuff and run your test then?

Comment: I am able to run tests without categories. Also I am able to run tests by categories from the Suites, but I don't like this solution.